# Position ViewPager within CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager within a CoordinatorLayout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
/>
```

It's a little faint in the picture, but the blue box is after the toolbar.

> [image]

It puts the ViewPager after the ToolBar and TabBar, but the height extends too much. I want the height to fill the parent.

If I remove the layout behavior it works, but I don't know how much the marginTop should be (there's the ActionBar's height + TabBar's height).

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
/>
```

> [image]

**I want to have the ViewPager be after the toolbar and extend to the end of the device.**

This is the entire XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    tools:context=".MainView">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is because of your current configuration of the `app:layout_scrollFlags`. If you don't android to push the ViewPager down set it to an empty String `app:layout_scrollFlags=""`. You can change its behavior afterwards if you need/have/want to.

you should wrap the AppBarLayout and the ViewPager in the CoordinatorLayour and add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`  to the ViewPager. That line does the trick. Avoid that the content of your ViewPager goes behind the Toolbar/TabLayout

Comment: The AppBarLayout and the ViewPager are both within the CoordinatorLayout and the layout behavior is set. The height of the ViewPager extends outside of the device screen. Is it possible to make the height stay within bounds?

Comment: the ViewPager is a Scrollable Widget. Its height goes outside the screen if you have more content that you can display in one screen. What exactly the problem? The Preview?

Comment: I think I understand now. The actionbar was set to scroll, so fill_height will actually take that into account. I simply set `app:layout_scrollFlags=""` so now the actionbar doesn't scroll and fill_height doesn't extend outside of the screen.

Comment: Removing the scrollFlags prevents the toolbar from collapsing tho.